# JavaFX 8 Animations

Tags: animation, javafx

I am trying to create a continuous animation, eventually the goal would be a bouncing ball that bounces off the edges of the screen, however, one step at a time.

I started with the sample code from Oracle that has an animation of circles that move for 40 seconds.

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage) 
{
    Group root = new Group();
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 800, 600);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);



    Group circles = new Group();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) 
    {
       MovingCircle circle = new MovingCircle(150, Color.web("white", 0.05));
       circle.setStrokeType(StrokeType.OUTSIDE);
       circle.setStroke(Color.web("black", 0.16));
       circle.setStrokeWidth(4);
       circles.getChildren().add(circle);
    }
    root.getChildren().add(circles);





    Timeline timeline = new Timeline();
    timeline.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
    for (Node circle: circles.getChildren()) 
    {
            if(circle instanceof MovingCircle)
            {
                MovingCircle c = (MovingCircle)circle;

                timeline.getKeyFrames().addAll(
           /* new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO, // set start position at 0
                new KeyValue(circle.translateXProperty(), random() * 800),
                new KeyValue(circle.translateYProperty(), random() * 600)
            ),*/
            new KeyFrame(new Duration(10), // set end position at 40s
                c.getXMovement(), c.getYMovement())

            );
                c.updateCenter();
            }

    }
    // play 40s of animation
    timeline.play();



    primaryStage.show();
}
```

I created a new MovingCircle that extends Circle to try and add other stuff to it later.  The two new class methods return exactly what was commented out from the default code given.

I changed the cycle to indefinite so that it would go forever.  All the circle does though is bounce between its original starting point and the translated point.  I have tried updating its center location in hopes that the next bounce would move it to a different location, however, that doesn't work.

I am at quite a loss as to what to try next to get this working more the way I was hoping.

Comment: If you want a ball bouncing off the edges of some rectangle, indefinitely, you're not going to be able to calculate all the possible "target values" ahead of time (and, in theory at least, it will not necessarily cycle through a finite number of paths). So a timeline, which represents a finite transition that can be repeated an arbitrary number of times, is not the right choice. I would recommend an `AnimationTimer`. [Here](https://gist.github.com/james-d/8327842) is a (much more complex) example of using an animation timer for bouncing balls.

Comment: I will check that out, thank you.  This is my first time trying to use anything within JavaFX so I really wasn't sure if I was even on the correct path.  Appreciate the link.

Comment: That is actually exactly what I was looking for.  I had created that in Swing, bouncing off each other with collisions and all, and was trying to reproduce it in JavaFX.  Thank you again.